# CSS transforms do not transition until end of animation in safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, css-animations

Fiddle of issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/x0j3aLsr/7/

I'm trying to animate a circle into covering the whole screen with a nice transition. This is working on Firefox and Chrome (so I expect not a Webkit issue), but for some reason not in Safari.  While the ending states are correct, it looks like the `transform` property does not actually transition, it just "jumps" at the end.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or is it just a bug in Safari?

Comment: Did you try declaring your CSS functions with webkit prefix ? -webkit-transition, -webkit-transform, etc.

Comment: Yup @Zetura, you can try it there in the fiddle and see that it still has the same effect.  Latest safari supports normal transform syntax: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: The problem is that you change the translateY from 0 to 50%, and Safari seems to not be able to calculate. If you place your bubble at top 50% from the start, and translateY to 50% (so you can remove the transform in the active class), it's working : https://jsfiddle.net/Zetura/x0j3aLsr/8/. So you will just have to animate the top attribute instead of translateY.

Comment: @Zetura thanks for the suggestion.  This is a simple example, the real implementation involves multiple circles positioned responsively based on width and height (so I can't use absolute values).  Therefore, I'm not sure I can accurately calculate positions using `top` alone (since it will be halfway cut off, like if I set it to 0% in your example).  But I will give it a try and let you know.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I don't think you will be able to make the transition from responsive position to full screen without using the position absolute. So...

Comment: @zetura But it works in the other browsers... :P